# Why is VNC slow to display the initial frames?

Tags: vnc, ssh-tunnel

I have a Windows 7 PC running a VNC server, and a Linux (CentOS 7) machine. The Windows 7 machine runs a batch script wrapped around `plink` to maintain an outgoing SSH tunnel to the Linux machine, with remote port forwarding for the VNC port; on the Linux machine I then run a VNC viewer, pointing it at the local VNC port, which forwards over the tunnel and connects to the VNC server on the Windows machine.

When I start the VNC viewer on the Linux machine, the VNC authentication screen is displayed almost instantaneously, so I know there is no issue with making the initial connection. However, when I enter the username and password, nothing happens for a good 5 or 6 seconds before the first frame of the Windows 7 desktop background is displayed. Once the first frame is displayed, the speed of the VNC connection generally is no problem at all (it does vary somewhat depending on what else is going on, but it's rarely problematic).

What is happening during this 5 or 6 second delay, and which end should I be peering suspiciously at? The SSH tunnel means that a Wireshark log taken from either end is of little value.

Comment: I'd say this is normal behavior and shouldn't be of any concern. I doubt you'll be able to fix it either.

Comment: Hmm, OK. It didn't used to happen (a while ago, I can't be any more specific because I don't remember exactly when it changed) and I was wondering what might have changed to make it happen. I should have been clearer in the post that it hasn't always done this. It's really annoying because everything else about the connection is perfectly fast, it's just that first frame.